# Mysql Nodejs with react front end is not returning any data from select statement, and result . length returning []

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have used Mysql as backend for react application. my motive was to verify if username already exist in the database and return 'done' if not exist and return 'username exist' if already exists
my** Mysql server (node.js) code **is as follows:

```
const cors=require("cors");
    const { response } = require("express");
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const mysql=require("mysql");
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    const db=mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password:"password",
        database:"ggsklogin",
    });
app.post("/checkusersk",(req,res)=>{
        const username=req.body.usernamea;
    db.query("select username from skcred where username=username;",
    (err,results)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send({err});
        }
         if(results.length>0){
            res.send(results);

        }
        else{   
            res.send({message:"done"});
        }
       
        
    });
    });
app.listen(3001,()=>{
        console.log("running on 3001") 
    });
```

**front end:
newlogin.jsx**:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { useState,useNavigate,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
function Newlogin() {
    const[usernamea,setusername]=useState('')
    const[password,setpassword]=useState('')
    const[repeatpass,setreapeatpass]=useState('')
    const[loginstatus,setLoginstatus]=useState('')
    const check=()=>{
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/checkusersk', {
           username: usernamea,
        }).then((response)=>{
            if(response.data){
            setLoginstatus(response.data.message);}
            else{
                setLoginstatus(response.data[0].username)
            }
            
        })

        }
    return ( 
        <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder='enter username' name='username' onChange={(e)=>{setusername(e.target.value)}}/>
            <input type="password" placeholder='enter password' name='password' onChange={(e)=>{setpassword(e.target.value)}}/>
            <input text="password" placeholder='repeat password' name='repeatpass' onChange={(e)=>{setreapeatpass(e.target.value)}}/>
    
            <button onClick={check}></button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h5>{loginstatus}</h5>
        </div>
      
        </div>
     );
}

export default Newlogin;
```

**database : mysql**

```
select * from skcred;
+--------------+----------+
| username     | password |
+--------------+----------+
| asadasasd    | dsaad    |
| asdd         | dasd     |
| asdd         | dasd     |
| sada         | ads      |
| sada         | ads      |
| sada         | ads      |
| sada         | ads      |
| sada         | ads      |
| sada         | ads      |
| sada         | ads      |
| sdaaaaaaaaaa | aaaa     |
| abiinaya     | sridhar1 |
| abinayaa     | assf     |
| abinayaa     | assf     |
| asdf         | asdf     |
| asdf         | asdf     |
| asdf         | asdf     |
| assa         | werr     |
| dddddd       | ddddd    |
+--------------+----------+
```

i have tried to debug this a lot of times. i have also tried :
select count(username) from skcred;
if it could display results, but the data inside it is showing as [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the query you area executing is

SELECT * FROM SKCRED WHERE username='username'

You have to make sure that it is your variable *username* and not the string that is sent in the request

```
const cors=require("cors");
    const { response } = require("express");
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const mysql=require("mysql");
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    const db=mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password:"password",
        database:"ggsklogin",
    });
app.post("/checkusersk",(req,res)=>{
        const username=req.body.username;
    db.query(`select username from skcred where username=${username};`,
    (err,results)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send({err});
        }
         if(results.length>0){
            res.send(results);

        }
        else{   
            res.send({message:"done"});
        }
       
        
    });
    });
app.listen(3001,()=>{
        console.log("running on 3001") 
    });
```

Comment: thank you sooo much....u have helped a lot